# Openssl aes-256-cbc in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

I want to encode randomly generated token with aes-256-cbc in bash. When I write this code in shell:

```
echo -n 8724eb94-ff8f-441e-81a7-bc4282f7c342 | openssl enc -a -e -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:fzJKp5/vYUWZUZ1hVSXycdmskKcSNtmZoFhPv5UtWGuoV9yH61JCjKzXUWmRCJJ9FITOi66ANSDpBJZKjrRFjA==
```

I get: **HdkTpAnsJ+bHi0DggaQq3iJMh0mrgcohOiJDeGzpqLFdvZUEXaD3YBEqGa4rBB7Y** - and it is the same as in Node.js crypto module.

But! When I write this code in bashscript:

```
hash=$(echo -n 8724eb94-ff8f-441e-81a7-bc4282f7c342 | openssl enc -a -e -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:fzJKp5/vYUWZUZ1hVSXycdmskKcSNtmZoFhPv5UtWGuoV9yH61JCjKzXUWmRCJJ9FITOi66ANSDpBJZKjrRFjA==);

echo ${hash}
```

I get **alphrNunU02O4Xxw+qVgaEEaZGTrdGenvgsGnt0lczOkGKX5l6rAQTY3EJ8VA0iB** and I have no idea why and where is bug. I have tried using ``, but with same wrong encoded value.

I have never write anything in bash, so I have no idea about some "tricks".

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: Copied and pasted your lines into a script file and ran it. Worked fine here. Are you sure that's the code you are running?

Comment: Yes, i have checked it 10 times and i always get alphr...

Comment: What do you see if you add `declare -p hash` right above and below that `hash=` line in the script?

Comment: How did you invoke your "bashscript" (?) Could you edit your question by showing an actual _session_ of your bash depicting the problem? Maybe the real issue is outside the few lines you have identified for now.

Comment: @EtanReisner I can see this: declare -- hash="alphrNunU02O4Xxw+qVgaEEaZGTrdGenvgsGnt0lczOkGKX5l6rAQTY3EJ8VA0iB"

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - I am using 'sh script.sh' to run this script

Comment: Could you type `cat script.sh` then `sh ./script.sh` and show a screenshot showing those two commands and their result please.

Comment: @KrzysztofKukiełka Is that output from before or after the openssl line in your script?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have using:

```
'sh script.sh'
```

to run my script. But when I have done this:

```
'bash script.sh'
```

everything works perfectly. I have no idea why (yet) and now I will look for answer for 'What is thy difference between 'sh' and 'bash' '.

Thank you for some suggestions!

Comment: This sounds like either a pre-existing `hash` variable that you can't overwrite or your sh doesn't like something about the sub-shell command and you are encrypting an error message.

Comment: Could you type `bash -c "echo $hash"`

Comment: I get empty line in console, after `bash -c "echo $hash"`